# How to grant access for a Google Cloud Service Account to have all the same permissions as a another Service Account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-iam, google-cloud-identity

So I have a Google Cloud Service Account one `sa-1@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com` that has access to roles A and B.

There is Service Account two `sa-2@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com` which I need to have access to roles A, B, *and* C.

How do I get `sa-2` to have the same access as `sa-1` and some other access too?

I tried to add `sa-2` as a principal to `sa-1` with the `Service Account Admin` role.

1. IAM & Admin
2. Service Accounts
3. Select `sa-1`
4. "+ Grant Access"
5. Specify `sa-2` in dropdown for `New principals`
6. Click "Save"

But there is still access denied on the GCP service using the `sa-2` account.

I'm trying to get an inherited relationship between the two SAs.

Comment: If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.

Answer (score 1):

In order to grant a Google Cloud Service Account the same permissions as Service Account1, you will need to grant Service Account2 the `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` role on the Service Account1. This will allow Service Account 2 to inherit the roles granted to Service Account 1, and you can then grant additional roles to Service Account 2 to give it additional access. You can do this by going to the IAM page in the Google Cloud Console and setting the role to Service Account User for Service Account 2..

For more information follow this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-role).

Comment: I'm still having issues with access even after doing this.  I even tried with "Editor" access between the relationship between the two SAs.  I also gave Service Account User, Service Account Admin, and Service Account Key Admin for all SAs for SA2 with the same result.  The reason might be due to I'm using an SA key from SA2.